# Groovy Spread Operator with Spock Framework Mock "_" option inside

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I am new to groovy and Spock.

I'm trying to create a generic method for mocking objects in my system.

**the problem**

I'm trying to create a function that will get an object and dynamically mock the functions I want in the object.
the function gets a map of functions with data when to mock each of one them and what to return.
the functions return an error.

I created a class

```
    class MetaData {
    Object[] argTypes
    def returnValue
    Object[] argsMatchers

    MetaData(Object[] argTypes, returnValue, Object[] argsMatchers) {
        this.argTypes = argTypes
        this.returnValue = returnValue
        this.argsMatchers = argsMatchers
    }
}
```

the mocking function is:

```
    def mockFunctionTestData(Map overrides = [:], def clazz){
    def args = Mock(clazz)
    overrides.each { String key, value ->
        Object[] argTypes = value.argTypes
        if(args.metaClass.respondsTo(args, key, argTypes).size() == 1){
            def methodToGetRequest = key
            def argsMatchers = value.argsMatchers
            def returnValue = value.returnValue

            args."$methodToGetRequest"(*argsMatchers) >> returnValue
        } else {
            println "Error: Trying to add property that doesn't exist"
        }
    }
    return args
}
```

I'm creating the object :

```
def functionData = new MetaData([Date, Date, List, boolean] as Object[],
      meas,
      [_ as Date, _ as Date, new ArrayList<>(), true] as Object[]) //the line that fails
def dogDAO = [getDogData: functionData]


def testDog= mockFunctionTestData(dogDAO , Dog)
```

the code above returns the following exception:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '_' with class 'org.spockframework.lang.Wildcard' to class 'java.util.Date' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Date(org.spockframework.lang.SpreadWildcard)
```

**the line that fails**

```
[_ as Date, _ as Date, new ArrayList<>(), true] as Object[])
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spock Framework, you can't create a mock in such a dynamic fashion. Spock has its own compiler (AST Transformation to be precise) which creates an executable test code. Only when in interaction section, does it recognize "_" as a wildcard symbol and ">>" operator to return a fixed value. That's why you get that exception. Because "_" wildcard is not in an interaction section. I'd suggest writing your test similar to the following:

```
class DogSpec extends Specification {
    def "test the dog"() {
        when:
        def dog = Mock(Dog) {
            1 * getDogData(_ as Date, _ as Date, new ArrayList<>(), true) >> "Bark"
        }

        then:
        dog.getDogData(new Date(), new Date(), [], true) == "Bark"
    }
}
```

- [Where to declare interactions](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_where_to_declare_interactions)
- [Declaring Interactions at Mock Creation Time](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#declaring-interactions-at-creation-time)
- [Returning Fixed Values](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_returning_fixed_values)

Comment: thanks @Dmitry, I tried something like you wrote before I went on the generic way. Just wanted to try a generic way. I think it's not possible